# Должен ли браузер отправлять Cookie с OPTIONS запросами?

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, cookie, cors

При попытке отправить cors запрос методом POST с ContentType: application/json, браузер отправляет предварительный запрос методом OPTIONS, но не отправляет с ним куки, так что API заварачивает OPTIONS запрос с 401 статусом. Нормальное ли это поведение для API и браузера, и должен ли он вообще слать куки в данном случае? С остальными запросами куки уходят нормально. Где-то в спецификациях освещается этот вопрос?

Answer (score 0):

Это "CORS предварительный запрос":

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-preflight-fetch

Спецификацию понять сложно, но люди говорят, что для браузера это нормально.

Я обычно CORS не использую, проще всё пропустить через сервер с одним именем.